# Checkbox Hidden Div Unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, yii

I have a checkbox hidden div with text field. If checkbox is checked this text field will showed, but if checkbox unchecked text field not show. This Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("input[name='checkbox1']").click(function () {

            if ($("#checkyes1").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvcheckbox1").show('lainnya');

            } else {

                $("#dvcheckbox1").hide('lainnya');
            }



        });
    });
</script>

<div style="margin-left: 29%; margin-top: -2%;">
<label for="checkyes1">

<input type="checkbox" id="checkyes1" name="checkbox1" value="lainnya" />
Lainnya
</label>

<div id="dvcheckbox1" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'lainnya'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

But, How this checkbox is checked if there something value on textfield? and text field shown. Because in form Update, value was show but checkbox is checked. I want checkbox is checked

For example Like this:
[Click to show example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOji2.png)

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Your code appears to work fine. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: In form update, value in text field was show, but checkbox is unchecked. I want checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use with `change` event with `.toggle(boolean)` method:

```
// on page load check of the div contains any text
$("#dvcheckbox1").toggle(function(){
   var $v = $(this).find('input').val();
   $("input[name='checkbox1']").prop('checked', $v.trim().length !== 0)
   return $v.trim().length !== 0;
});    

$("input[name='checkbox1']").change(function () {
     $("#dvcheckbox1").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: thanks It's work. But sorry about my language. Still studying @Jai

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here:

1 - Better if you use document ready, because it waits until all the elements are loaded.

2 - You should hide the element$("#dvcheckbox1").hide('lainnya') when the page is loaded.

3 - A listener in the input:text is a good idea. It enables the checkbox if the textbox is empty.

Please, have a look at the next piece of code:

```
<div>
    <label for="checkyes1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkyes1" name="checkbox1" value="lainnya" />
        Lainnya
    </label>

    <div id="dvcheckbox1">
        <label for="myValuye"/>
        <input type="text" id="myValue" name="myValue" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='checkbox1']").click(function () {
        // Always use some logs to check what line are you reaching.
        console.log("Clicked checkbox!!!");

        if ($("#checkyes1").is(":checked")) {
            $("#dvcheckbox1").show('lainnya');
        } else {
            console.log("Value: " + $("#myValue").val());
            $("#dvcheckbox1").hide("lainnya");
        }
    });

    $("#myValue").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $("#checkyes1").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#checkyes1").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    // First of all we hide the #dvcheckbox1
    $("#dvcheckbox1").hide('lainnya');
})
```